# new File(path, name) vs file.mkDirs()

Tags: android, file

I have been learning File manipulation where I have found a "problem" I am unable to understand.

Basically, I first came to believe that

```
new File (getFilesDir(), "myFile.txt");
```

creates a File with desired name in desired path. 
However, I have found examples where this is used only to reference an existing file on the application which was beforehand created using

```
file.mkdirs();
```

Therefore, can some one please explain the difference and what the File acctually points at in this case.

Comment: `new File (getFilesDir(), "myFile.txt")` creates a new `File` object, not an actual file on disk.  Methods like `File::exists`, `File::isFile`, `File::isDirectory`, `File::createNewFile` etc .. can be used, have a look at the docs - https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Mark mentioned, `File(File parent, String child)` only creates a `File` object and not the actual directory and file in your local drive.

`mkdir()` is the method that creates the actual directory according to the path provided in the `File()` constructor.